# MongoDB, NodeJS. Get element from promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have request to DB with promises, I want to extract 2 values("latitude" and "longitude") for all documents and put it to array.

I'm doing like this;

```
const promises = [
    dbo.collection("users").find({ name: "Mark" }, { latitude: 1, longitude: 1, _id: 0 }).toArray()
]
Promise.all(promises).then(function (Presults) {
        console.log(Presults);


    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

as a result I get all fields, for example: name, gender, latitude, longitude etc. 
When I try to specify that I want only latitude, longitude, I always get result **undefined** 
What I've tried: `console.log(Presults.latitude);`
console.log(Presults[0].latitude);

But I want get output array like this

```
[
    { lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312 },
    { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
    { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
    { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 }
];
```

I tested without promises, it works:

```
    dbo.collection("users").find(
    { name: "Mark" },
    { latitude: 1, longitude: 1, _id: 0 }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var array1 = [];
        var z = { "lat": result[0].latitude, "lng": result[0].longitude };
        var y = { "lat": result[0].latitude, "lng": result[0].longitude };
        array1.push(z, y);

        console.log(array1);
    });
```

Comment: can you show what exactly you get when you `console.log(Presults);` this

Comment: Could you add what exacly you got with `console.log(Presults);`?

Comment: try replacing `{latitude: 1, longitude: 1, _id: 0}` with `'+latitude +longitude -_id'`...

Comment: This is what I get: [
  [
    {
      _id: 'fiougisudfgy890-milmb:AP897rjhkgs9SooLQSqgXQqfPmHbIV166kL7ojR4n456734523AuOTv6KSbQZiLZZerty456jz7VwlqzQN',
      name: 'Mark',
      token: 'fPKrkfirog38960-milmb:APA91bGeK3OavT704978iofghbQZiLZZOHb6pLP39836ghqzQN',
      email: 'DefaultEmail@gmail.com',
      Aid: '860a8ggirpww4565b2d',
      OS: '9',
      latitude: 26.521511,
      longitude: 52.1424
    }
  ]
]

Comment: Ashwyn, this is not changing anything. It is just for search. My problem is with extraction data from result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    const data = results.flatMap(v => v.map(k => ({ lat: k.latitude, lng: k.longitude})))

    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: it is not changing anything, it still returns full list of elements. I need to output only two parameters: latitude and longitude.

Comment: I have updated the answer, u need to remove toArray() from the promise first

Comment: output of your code is: [ { lat: undefined, lng: undefined } ]     btw, valued in DB in double. I tried with toArray() and without - result is the same

Comment: can u show what comes when you do a console.log(results)

Comment: it is too big to post as a comment, it is smth like this [
  Cursor {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: 16,

Comment: Can you put the toArray() back to promise and show me what console.log(results) yields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214974/discussion-between-shijil-narayanan-and-andrei-charnyshou).